# Does TLS matter for http protocol?

Tags: http, web, tls1.2

I want to understand if I visit a URL using http

for eg. http://foo.com

The TLS level doesn't matter here - right?

TLS only makes sense when we have https.

Please correct me if I am wrong..

I have developed an API and my consumer is unable to call and they think it is due to TLS but I have developed a HTTP API. So I am thinking if this would matter at all on http API.

I think not! Please confirm.

Comment: Your consumer may require https. If they make an XHR to a non-secure http (your api) then it would throw up an error about insecure content on a secure page if they are making that request from a secure page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you developed a http API and the consumer used it with https then it wont work. Otherwise your API should be worked properly with http calls. Furthermore Check your firewall setting because some times server firewall block http calls when the port is not allowed through the firewall settings.